# What is the purpose to use array notation to access object property in for..in loop?

Tags: javascript

Currently i'm reading You Don't Know JS series.

I'm unable to understand one line in this code which is **console.log( k, myObject[k] )**

```
var myObject = { };
Object.defineProperty(
 myObject,
 "a",
 { enumerable: true, value: 2 }
);
Object.defineProperty(
 myObject,
 "b",
 { enumerable: true, value: 3 }
);

for (var k in myObject) {
 console.log( k + ' -> ' + myObject[k] );
}
```

Why author uses array notation to access object properties?

If i modify the code like this[ to access object property through object property accessor ] **console.log( k, myObject.k)**

I'm getting undefined values in console.

Why it's showing undefined if access through object property accessor?
And what is the purpose to use array like notation to access object property??

Comment: Sometimes you don't know the keys of your object. When looping like this you get them and will be able to access the values.

Comment: If the property name is a variable, there's just no other way. You can only use dot notation for literals (at not all literals, just those that don't have special characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the property accessor is like using a literal:

```js
var obj= {
  prop1: "Hello",
  name: "This is not prop1"
}

var prop1="name";

console.log(obj.prop1)
console.log(obj[prop1])
```

`obj.prop1` and `obj["prop1"]` are *almost equivalent* (see last example to find when they are not interchangeable), so if you don't know what the property name is when writing your code, you need to use the square brackets notation to parametrize it:

```
function getProperty(obj,prop) {
  return obj[prop];
}
```

Another reason to use this notation is when using attribute names that are not valid JS identifiers:
Given this object:

```
var obj= { "hello-world":"text here"}
```

The following expression is valid

`console.log(obj["hello-world"])`

The following expression is not valid because JS will try to find the value of `obj.hello` and then substract the value of `world`:

`console.log(obj.hello-world)`

Answer (score 1):

> Why author uses array notation to access object properties?

That isn't array notation.

`foo["x"]` (where `"x"` is something that is evaluated as a string) is how you access the property of an object.

You can also use `foo.x` but only if `x` is an identifier.

You can't use `.x` when the value is a number, because identifiers cannot start with a number (which is why you commonly see that method used to access properties of an array (which is just a type of object)).

You can't use `.x` when the value is in a variable (because you want to evaluate the variable and get the value of it, not use `"x"), which is why it is used here.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code below

```js
    var myObject = { };
    Object.defineProperty(
     myObject,
     "a",
     { enumerable: true, value: 2 }
    );
    Object.defineProperty(
     myObject,
     "b",
     { enumerable: true, value: 3 }
    );
    
    Object.defineProperty(
     myObject,
     "k",
     { enumerable: true, value: 4 }
    );
    
    for (var k in myObject) {
     console.log( k + ' -> ' + myObject.k );
    };
```

I have added property named 'k' and with this addition, the console.log outputs '4' and not 'undefined'. This shows how the javascript interpreter works as it looks for key name 'k' in the object. It does not look for value stored in variable k.